# 'DB Error - No Such Table' -- CiviCase in Drupal 7

Tags: civicase, database

I have a Drupal 7 + CiviCRM database with CiviCase.
This is a fairly new install. I would say CiviCRM was installed fresh about 3-4 months ago. As of now, CiviCRM has been upgraded to the latest current version, 5.25.0.

I noticed the following problem on 5.24, but as this is still a new install in development, its possible the problem has been there since the beginning.

When I go to Cases -> Dashboard, I see:

> DB Error: no such table

Additionally, when I go to view a Contact, and then click the "Cases" tab, I see the follow message in the upper right of the screen:

> Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser
>   and try again.

How should I go about fixing this?
It seems like the entire table structure is missing?

There is no production data in the CiviCase extension yet, so if it is possible to just do a complete fresh install of just that portion of CiviCRM, I can do that. I just don't know how I would do that safely without affecting the work I've done to other portions of the Drupal and CiviCRM database.

Here is the backtrace for when I see the DB error:

```
#9 /home/lapavnhy/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2696): DB_common->query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")#10 /home/lapavnhy/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1829): DB_DataObject->_query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#11 /home/lapavnhy/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(421): DB_DataObject->query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#12 /home/lapavnhy/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1540): CRM_Core_DAO->query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...", TRUE)#13 /home/lapavnhy/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php(537): CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#14 /home/lapavnhy/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/Page/DashBoard.php(71): CRM_Case_BAO_Case::getCases(NULL, (Array:0), "dashboard", TRUE)
#15 /home/lapavnhy/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/Page/DashBoard.php(100): CRM_Case_Page_DashBoard->preProcess()
#16 /home/lapavnhy/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(311): CRM_Case_Page_DashBoard->run((Array:2), NULL)
#17 /home/lapavnhy/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#18 /home/lapavnhy/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#19 /home/lapavnhy/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(454): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#20 /home/lapavnhy/example.com/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("case")
#21 /home/lapavnhy/example.com/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#22 {main}
```

Comment: can you also provide the sql statment?

Comment: Does the mysql user have create view permission? It sounds like maybe the db views didn't get created? e.g  
 `civicrm_view_case_activity_upcoming`   https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.25.0/CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php#L2829. Try disabling then reenabling civicase at admin - system settings - components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed in [chat](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/8ek6gxgdzibrzx95p9shf4c3he) the views hadn't been created and disabling and reenabling civicase at Administer - System Settings - Components fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for the help!